# QML not changing state

Tags: qml, qt4

I am creating an application but the state in qml is not changing....here `LoginView` is a QML file and `MessageView` is also a QML file i want to change QML files as pages of the application...I am doing something wrong but I am not able to figure out what....please help me

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
id: main

LoginView {
    id: login
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: true
    onLoginClicked: main.state="messageView"
}

MessageView {
    id: message
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false
}

states: [State {
        name:"messsageView"
        PropertyChanges { target: login; visible: false }
        PropertyChanges { target: message; visible: true }
    },State {
        name:""
        PropertyChanges { target: message; visible: false }
        PropertyChanges { target: login; visible: true }
    }]
}
```

Comment: `loginClicked` is a signal of the `LoginView` which is generated by Login Button. So, when the button is pressed i want to change view to `messageView`.

Comment: Are you sure that `onLoginClicked` signal is triggered somewhere inside your `LoginView` item? Please post that file too.

Comment: caught the error....its just that i have written state name `messsageView` instead of `messageView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't a change happen when some 'event' occurs. Something like this:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle
{

    id: main
    color: "blue"
    width : 200
    height: 200

Rectangle
{
    id: login
    color: "red"
    anchors.fill: parent
    opacity: 1
}

Rectangle {
    id: message
    color: "green"
    anchors.fill: parent
    opacity: 0
}

// --------------------------- THIS! ---------------------

MouseArea
{
 anchors.fill: parent
 onClicked: parent.state = "messsageView"
}

// -------------------------------------------------------

states: [State {
        name:"messsageView"
        PropertyChanges { target: login; opacity: 0 }
        PropertyChanges { target: message; opacity: 1 }
    },State {
        name:""
        PropertyChanges { target: message; opacity: 0 }
        PropertyChanges { target: login; opacity: 1 }
    }]

}
```

Comment: but there are `Button` Element in both QMLs which generate some event. i just want to connect that events to this main QML.

Comment: Why are you using opacity instead of visible? Why are you writing useless property changes for the default state?

Comment: @Matteo This was answered in '13, if I remember correctly there was no visible flag at that time in Qt.

Comment: That is not true, `visible` existed in qt 4.8 that was available in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You made ​​a typo.
Look to this code:

```
LoginView {
id: login
anchors.fill: parent
visible: true
onLoginClicked: main.state="messageView" //state name is "messageView"
}
```

and, secondary look to:

```
states: [State {
    name:"messsageView" // TRIPLE "s"
    PropertyChanges { target: login; opacity: 0 }
```